# Uploading Multiple Images to Amazon s3 with HTML, javascript & jQuery with Ajax Request (No PHP or Server)

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, image-upload, aws-sdk, multiple-file-upload

I am developing a website in HTML, javascript & jQuery. I want to upload (multiple images) to amazon s3 server in an ajax request. There is no such SDK to integrate s3 in Javascript. A PHP SDK is available, but it is not useful to me. Can anybody provide solution to this in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the article - [How to Upload Scanned Images to Amazon S3 Using Dynamic Web TWAIN](http://www.codepool.biz/ocr-barcode-twain/twain-sdk/upload-image-to-amazon-s3.html), which introduces how to use PHP and JavaScript to upload files to Amazon S3. Key steps include:

> 1. Specify the bucket which is the place or the folder name used for
>      storing data on Amazon S3
> 2. Specify the Access Key and Secret Key you
>      obtained from your Amazon S3 account
> 3. Create a policy that specifies
>      what you permit and what you don’t permit for the data uploaded from a
>      client web page
> 4. Encode and encrypt these policies and signatures to
>      keep them confidential, and store the encoded and encrypted values in
>      the hidden input elements.